# Why are <input>s also center vertically when making <span> center vertically? （<input>'s line-height not equals to its parent height）

Tags: html, css

**Notice: height of `<div>` is 50px, and line-height of `<span>` is also 50px**

> when don't apply 'line-height' to <span>, all elements align to the top of parent, when apply 'line-height: 50px' to <span>, why all elements be center vertically?

```html
<div class="block">
  <input type="text" class="inline-block-input">
  <span class="inline-block-text">*</span>
  <input type="text" class="inline-block-input">
</div>

<style>
  .block {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  
  .inline-block-input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  
  .inline-block-text {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 50px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

To understand what is happening add some text inside the input:

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, blue) 0 31px/100% 1px no-repeat;
}

.inline-block-input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: transparent;
  border:1px solid;
}

.inline-block-text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <input type="text" class="inline-block-input" value="text">
  <span class="inline-block-text">*bc</span>
  <input type="text" class="inline-block-input" value="text">
</div>
```

Notice how all the text are aligned the same way due to the fact that [the default vertical alignment is baseline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align). Your element seems to be centred but they are not. They are aligned following the baseline alignment and as a side effect you have your centring.

Change the alignment of the element and you will have a different behavior:

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, blue) 0 31px/100% 1px no-repeat;
}

.inline-block-input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: transparent;
  border:1px solid;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.inline-block-text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <input type="text" class="inline-block-input" value="text">
  <span class="inline-block-text">*bc</span>
  <input type="text" class="inline-block-input" value="text">
</div>
```

And without line-height on the span you will still have the baseline alignment:

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, blue) 0 21px/100% 1px no-repeat;
}

.inline-block-input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: transparent;
  border:1px solid;
}

.inline-block-text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <input type="text" class="inline-block-input" value="text">
  <span class="inline-block-text">*bc</span>
  <input type="text" class="inline-block-input" value="text">
</div>
```

Related questions to get more details:

[Vertical-align aligns everything else except self](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52634849/8620333)

[Inline elements and line-height](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28363186/8620333)

[Why is the descender “created” when baseline is set to vertical-align?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59008729/8620333)