# Span with vertical-align: middle expands height of a parent

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have spotted a strange behaviour of an `inline` or `inline-block` element with `vertical-align: middle` inside another `inline`/`inline-block`.

html

```
    <button id="button-1">
      <span><span class="one">Some text</span></span>
    </button>
    <button id="button-2">
      <span><span class="two">Some text</span></span>
    </button>
```

css

```
button {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 0;
}

span {
  line-height: 24px;
}

.one {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.two {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

`button-1` has `48px` height while `button-2` has `49.05px`.

You may want `vertical-align: middle` in case of buttons with multiple elements like icon + text. That's pretty strange that button's inner height becomes more then 24px line-height.
Of course it can be fixed with making button `inline-flex` and not using `vertical-align` but still confusing.
The main question: is there a way to do not use flexbox leave `vertical-align: middle` and preserve needed height of the button?

There is a sandbox to play with https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-glitter-uxjx39?file=/styles.css

Comment: This is all to do with the space created to accomodate text 'descenders'. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59008729/12571484

Comment: Yes, it does that. What's your question?

Comment: @Alohci
two questions: why? is there a way to avoid it?
I have noticed that this is happening only when I am wrapping span inside span. But that's how layout is in angular material 14 button. flexbox isn't an option because it breaks default multiline behaviour

Comment: With the `.two` span, you've got two 24px height boxes vertically offset from one another. The button height is from the top of the upper span to the bottom of the lower. Reduce the line height of the `.two` span to remove the overlap.

Comment: @Alohci wow, you a magician bro. Would you like to post an answer and I will approve it? I have edited my question to include a real question

Comment: @Alohci actually I have checked and span is looking shifted when I am setting lesser line-height to the inner span